# Google Analytics Android: Screen View are sent but never received

Tags: android, google-analytics

I implemented Google Analytics on an Android app. I can't see any page visit event on Google Analytics. I use `HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder` as such:

```
tracker.setScreenName("PlaceDetail"); // example name I do use
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
Log.e(TAG, "sendShowScreenEvent: screenName='"+screenName+"'");
```

I send those event in the `Fragment` `onStart()` method.

The log method is called each time properly, but the event does not appear on GA.
What is weird is that if I send normal events with `HitBuilders.EventBuilder()`, they do appear on Google Analytics.
It's not a question of delay, I waited days and still no page visit.

Any ideas :-) ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any luck resolving it already? :)

Comment: No :-( didn't get to work on it again